# Binding Data to DropDownList in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making a website inside the Visual Studio using asp.net.
My website is connected to Web Serbice Server which is connected to SQL database.

On my mainpage.aspx, at the top of the file, I have the first following line:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="mainpage.aspx.cs"
Inherits=WebApplication.mainpage" %>
```

Later in the same mainpage.aspx file I have a dropdown list:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" width="140px"></asp:DropDownList>
```

In my mainpage.aspx.cs file I'm writing the following code inside the Pade_Load() :

```
DataSet Company = WebSerivce.Company(IP, DataBaseName, UserName, Password);
DataTable cTable = Company.Table[0];

if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
DropDownList1.DataSource = cTable;
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID_Comp";
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Comp_Name";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

SQL DataBase Table:

```
ID_Comp     | int          | (Primary Key)
----------------------------
Comp_Name   | nvarchar(50) |
```

What am I doing wrong? I've followed the instructions of multiple tutorials but nothing so far has worked. Is there something fundamental I'm missing?

Comment: Are you getting value in cTable?

Comment: "Using Debugging" . ..1.Keep a Debug Point  at "Dataset Company" 2. Run the Application .. Execution will hold at that point and  you can see the Value in c Table

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `cTable` has data in it.
I tested your code below (commenting out the service part) and using a local Northwind database and it worked just fine. So, again, make sure the service is actually returning valid data into `cTable`. Place a debugger breakpoint and check the contents of `cTable`.

```
//DataSet Company = WebSerivce.Company(IP, DataBaseName, UserName, Password);
//DataTable cTable = Company.Table[0];
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ToString();
SqlDataSource dataSource = new SqlDataSource(conn, "select * from region"); 
DataSourceSelectArguments args = new DataSourceSelectArguments();
DataView view = dataSource.Select(args) as DataView;

DataTable cTable = view.ToTable(); 

if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    DropDownList1.DataSource = cTable;
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "RegionID";
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "RegionDescription";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

Browser dropdown list result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below. This way you can find if you are binding empty datatable or not. Based on this we can further troubleshoot.

```
        DataTable cTable = null;
        DataSet Company = WebSerivce.Company(IP, DataBaseName, UserName, Password);

        if (Company != null && Company.Tables[0] != null)
            cTable = Company.Tables[0];

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if(cTable != null && cTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DropDownList1.DataSource = cTable;
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID_Comp";
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Comp_Name";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                DropDownList1.DataSource = new DataTable();
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
                DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
            }


        }
```

Comment: Well, if `cTable` is, for some reason `null`, what's will happen with Your code `if(cTable.Rows.Count >0)` ?? I think some error will rise. So, I think it's better to replace that code with `if (Company != null && Company.Tables[0] != null) { cTable = Company.Tables[0]; ...` and rest of Your code.